# Find $P[D\leq 12.25$ feet$]$ where $D=\sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2}$

Tags: probability

The distance in feet by which a parachutist misses a target is $D=\sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2}$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent with $X_1 \sim N(0,25)$. Find $P[D\leq 12.25$ feet$]$.

I thought it would be handy to first take the square on both sides of the asked probability. Then I used the moment generating function of $X_1$ to find the expected value and variance of $X_1^2$. However, I then realised that there is no information given about $X_2$. What am I missing here? Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Are you sure $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not identically distributed?

Comment: @Alex, yes I am, this is the exactly the question as it is stated in my book. Maybe there is an error in the question though :/.

Comment: @Alex: The above problem appears in Introduction to probability and mathematical statistics on Pg 255 and is given as follows:
The distance in feet by which a parachutist misses a target is $D = \sqrt {X_1^2 + X_2^2}$ , where $X \sim N(0,25)$.

Comment: @jay-sun: ok, then $X$ probably implies that both variables are Normal with 0 mean and variance of 25

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assuming $X_1$ and $X_2$ are identically distributed with $X \sim N (0,\sigma^2)$. The distribution of $D$ follows a Rayleigh distribution which has the following form:

[image]

Should be straightforward to calculate your answer now.